# how to save ODBC datasource username and password in excel?

Tags: sql, oracle, odbc, ms-office

i am trying to connect with sql and oracle database from excel i want save username and password

Answer (score 0):

after providing username and password you have the options above to save password in file that file available in MyDataSources.